# I want to change the JSTL code in the script to Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, jstl

I want to change the JSTL code in the script to Thymeleaf

Because it is an HTML file, JSTL is not recognized.
request

I don't know how to change the path to the script.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "_how to change the path to the script_" - but when using inline Thymeleaf in JavaScript, you need to change `<script>` to `<script th:inline="javascript">`. See [JavaScript Inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining).

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of text. Add the text (formatted appropriately) to the question, instead. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) for more details.